# Weakly defining function at link-time, and testing for override

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, c++11, binutils

(Environment: gcc 4.6, c++11, glibc 2.13, binutils 2.21)

Please consider the follow "linking" demo for background:

**foo.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

void foo();
```

**foo1.cpp**:

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo1";
}
```

**foo2.cpp**:

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo2";
}
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

**Makefile**:

```
compile: main.o foo1.o foo2.o

case1: compile
    g++ -o case1.x main.o

case2: compile
    g++ -o case2.x main.o foo1.cpp

case3: compile
    g++ -o case3.x main.o foo1.o foo2.o

clean:
    rm *.o *.x
```

We have a function declaration as follows:

```
void foo();
```

and we have multiple definitions of it, one in foo1.cpp and a different one in foo2.cpp.

We compile the .cpp files into .o files:

```
$ make compile
```

No problem, main.o, foo1.o and foo2.o are produced.

**Case 1**

We then try and link just main.o:

```
$ make case1
error: undefined reference to 'foo()'
```

Ok, main.o references foo but no definition has been linked.

**Case 2**

Now we try and link main.o and foo1.o

```
$ make case2
```

There is a single definition of foo in foo1.o, so it links without error.

**Case 3**

Now we try and link main.o foo1.o and foo2.o

```
$ make case3
error: multiple definition of 'foo()'
```

The linker finds two definitions of foo in foo1.o and foo2.o, so rather than taking a random one it fails fast with an error and doesn't link.

**Questions**

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to mark the definition of foo1.cpp's version of foo (possibly with some sort of gcc attribute or pragma) as "weak"?  Meaning specifically that I want the behavior of case 1 and case 2 to remain the same, while the behavior of case 3 changes to successfully link without warning or error and the definition of foo in foo2.cpp is linked (overriding the "weak" definition in foo1.cpp).
2. Is it possible to test at runtime (and assign to a boolean variable) whether the weak version of foo was linked, or the strong one (without executing the function obviously). ie implement a function in main as follows.

   ```
   template<typename FunctionPtr>
   bool is_weak_linked(FunctionPtr fp);
   ```

is_weak_linked(foo) should return true in case 2 and false in case 3.

Comment: If you google "gcc weak attribute" you get useful results...

Comment: huh? "google" - what a silly name - whatever it is, it will never catch on

Comment: Why do you want `is_weak_linked`?  Or weak linking altogether?  There's almost certainly a more elegant or more portable solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To #1:

```
void foo() __attribute__((weak));
void foo()
{
    ...
}
```

To #2: I don't believe so, not with the static linking you're doing.  That information is lost at link time.

**Edit**

You can always abstract your way around #2.  Some examples:

```
// Foo.h
extern void foo();
extern "C" void default_foo();
extern const bool is_weak_foo_linked;
template <void (*)()> bool is_weak_linked();

// Foo1.cc
extern "C" void default_foo() {...}
void foo() __attribute__((weak, alias("default_foo")));

extern const bool __attribute__((weak)) is_weak_foo_linked=true;
template <> bool is_weak_linked<foo>() __attribute__((weak));
template <> bool is_weak_linked<foo>() {return true;}

// Foo2.cc
void foo() {...}
extern const bool is_weak_foo_linked=false;
template <> bool is_weak_linked<foo>() {return false;}

// main.cc
#include "foo.h"
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    foo();
    std::cout<<is_weak_foo_linked<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<is_weak_linked<foo>()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<(foo==default_foo)<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to mark the weak version with some sort of user defined attribute that survives until runtime?

Comment: @user1131467: The signatures would have to be identical, or else its an overload and theres no link problems.

Comment: @MooingDuck: ehh, I suppose it depends on how low level you want to go.  You could always do something really nasty, like mark the weak version with a detectable byte sequence in its machine code.  But we veer really far from C++ in doing so.